# Why does a bunch of leadfoot stuff run in the browser when starting my intern test?

Tags: selenium, intern, leadfoot

All,

Thank you in advance.

I am running a single functional test using intern and local selenium.  When I start the test, the following happens:

1. Chrome opens
2. Lots of stuff runs (not mine).
3. My test finally runs

I looked at the selenium output and tracked it down to this file:

`node_modules/leadfoot/Server.js`

It appears that this file is getting executed prior to my test.

I am also trying to run against browserStack and having issues with lots of GETs being called before my tests start.

My questions:
1. Is this just the way things work, or am I doing something wrong?
2. I understand that leadfoot makes the browser run faster. Is this how that happens?
3. Is there a way to disable this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are the feature detection tests, used to determine which functions in the Selenium server you are connecting to are broken, so Leadfoot/Intern can work around these server bugs for you. You can stop it by putting `fixSessionCapabilities: false` in your capabilities, but you should only do this if you know you are not using any of the defective APIs. The [complete list of detected capabilities](http://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/global.html#Capabilities) can be found in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

The capabilities in intern.js should be,

```
capabilities: {
    'selenium-version': '2.53.0',
    'idle-timeout': 1000,
    'fixSessionCapabilities': false
}
```

Where first one is the selenium standalone server version which we are using, second one is the timeout and third one that is 'fixSessionCapabilities', if set to false then directly test file will start running.